# SQL - Take Corresponding Value Where MIN(Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset with warehouse locations, dates, and inventory levels for given warehouse at a given date.

How do I structure a SQL query where I end up with a list of distinct locations and their inventory levels at the earliest date per warehouse? I'm thinking something like...

SELECT warehouse_id, (inventory_amt where min(date) is TRUE) as inventory

FROM inventory_table

GROUP BY warehouse_id

Comment: `SELECT WareHouseID, MIN(TheDate) FROM MyTable GROUP BY WareHouseID` cannot get any simpler than this.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm less interested in the actual minimum date...I need the inventory level at that earliest date.

Comment: use row_number ordered on TheDate ASC, and partitioned by WareHouseID , then use either a WITH or a subquery to select the row_number that is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE inventory_by_warehouse AS
SELECT
    a.warehouse_id
    ,a.inventory_amt
FROM inventory_table as a
WHERE a.date = 
    (SELECT min(date)
    FROM inventory_table
    WHERE warehouse_id = a.warehouse_id);
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like using `row_number()` and `top (1) with ties` for this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES it.*
FROM inventory_table it
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY warehouse_id ORDER BY date DESC);
```

You can also express this as:

```
select it.*
from inventory_table it
where it.date = (select max(it2.date)
                 from inventory_table it2
                 where it2.warehouse_id = it.warehouse_id
                );
```

Comment: since OP looks for the earliest date shouldn't this be ORDER BY date ASC??

Comment: Gotta love this query style (and generally whatever Gordon says).

Comment: Does this work for SQL Server via proc sql? I'm having trouble running it.

Comment: @tubaguy . . . It should if you are using native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
select warehouse_id,....
from  inventory_table t1
inner join (
select warehouse_id, min(date) from  inventory_table group py warehouse_id
) min
on t1.warehouse_id=min.warehouse_id
```